# Como excluir uma entidade pai sem excluir as entidades filhas?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Como faço, por annotations ou métodos para excluir, ou efetuar um `update` em uma entidade pai sem ser obrigado a excluir a entidade filha, ex:

```
public class Produto{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;
//...
@ManyToOne() //fetch.LAZY
Categoria categoria;

}

public class Categoria{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;
//...
@OneToMany(mappedby = "categoria") //fetch.LAZY
Produto produto;

}
```

Vemos que a minha classe `produto` é a classe filha da operação, o lado mais forte, que detém da `foreign key` de categoria, gostaria de poder excluir uma categoria, mesmo que esteja relacionada a um produto, atualizando a coluna `CATEGORIA_ID` da tabela para `NULL` talvez.

Mas quando tento fazer a exclusão gera um erro:

> ConstraintViolationException Não é possível excluir ou atualizar um registro que possui relacionamento.

Já tentei a propriedade `ORPHANREMOVAL = FALSE` e nada.

Comment: Não escreva em maiúsculas, porque dá a impressão que você está GRITANDO.

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta para tornar-la mais clara e legível, sugiro que leia [como formatar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: desculpe amigos, não farei isso de novo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione `nullable=true` no mapeamento da sua entidade filha e, no seu método de `delete()` da entidade pai, antes de efetivamente apagar essa entidade, você tem que setar `null` em todos os filhos relacionados a ela. Por exemplo (adapte para sua lógica, é só um exemplo):

```
public void deleteCategoria(int categoriaId) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // pesquise a categoria
    Categoria categoria = currentSession.get(Categoria.class, categoriaId);  
    //recupere os produtos        
    List<Produto> produtos = categoria.getProdutos();

    //sete o id de cada produto para null
    for(Produto produto : produtos) {
        produto.setCategoria(null);
    }

    //remova a categoria
    currentSession.remove(categoria);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou efetuar o teste, grande abraço !